# Image button focus isn't working

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I'm brand-new to Android, and I've been trying to make an image button with 3 images, for default, focused, and pressed.
I've tried a lot of the examples I've found, but I can't seem to make the button respond to focus.

I found the following example on this forum, and it displays the button, and responds to being pressed, but it doesn't change on focus.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: See this: [Android Developer: StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) Cheers!

Comment: just check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 0):

Are you using selectors for changing the drawable behind your button? For example, did you use `android:src="@drawable/selector1`. The selector code for your button should look like that (more description [here)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/but1_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/but1_focused" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/but1_default" />

</selector>
```

Comment: I've tried version of all the comments here, and the button appears, and responds to the click-  it just doesn't change on focus.   Is there some setting I'm missing?   Thanks

Comment: Maybe the button is not focusable somehow? Try adding to the button layout in xml: `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`. Also you can try calling Button.requestFocus() from java code just to test the focus function.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Make a new folder named color in the res

**2.** craete a .xml file like button.xml so it should look like res/color/button.xml

**3.** in the .xml write this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

**4.** in the layout set the background as @color/button.xml